# Why can't my file be found in my directory?

Tags: python, openai-whisper

I'm trying to use the openai-whisper library to transcribe text from a video in the same folder as my program. However, I keep getting a FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

This is my code:

```
import whisper
import os

directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
start = 0
videoList = []

for file in os.listdir(directory):
    if file.endswith('.mp4'):
        videoList.append(file)

model = whisper.load_model('base')

for video in videoList:
    start += 1
    result = model.transcribe(video)

    with open("Video " f'{start}' "transcription.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(result["text"] + '\n')
```

I get the error when I reach the line where I am trying to transcribe the video.

I tried to see if there was a problem with finding the files in my directory at first which is why I have that first for loop. I tried seeing if my program wasn't finding the mp4 files but it is.

Comment: Please provide the error message that you get.

Comment: `listdir()` returns the filename **without** the directory path. When you try to transcribe the file, you're implicitly referencing the current working directory, not the directory you originally found the fille in. I recommend you use [glob()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) instead.

Comment: Like @matbailie says - so, if the directory you're reading video files from isn't the working directory of the script, it can't find the file, since you're trying to open `somevideo.mp4` instead of `directory/somevideo.mp4`. Just add the filename to the directory and pass the resulting full path to the file (relative or absolute, doesn't matter) - note that the working directory for your script isn't necessarily the directory where the script is physically, which is what you're getting from `__file__`

Comment: @YuriGinsburg I provided the error message.

Comment: @Grismar It's in the working directory.  I'll try adding the directory instead of doing __file__ as I don't expect my instructor to manually change the directory when checking my assignment. I'll try glob() as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely confusion around the idea of a working directory. Every program on any OS has a working directory. This is the directory that the application will assume relative paths are relative to. So, when a program opens `test.txt`, it opens that file in the working directory. `test.txt` is a relative path, because it does not specify the full absolute path to the file (like `C:\Temp\test.txt`).

The working directory *can* be the same as the directory where the program or script is, but it's not a given. In this piece of code:

```
directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

... you determine the directory the script is in. But that does not have to be the working directory. For example, say your project looks like this:

```
\project_dir
  \src
    my_script.py
    video.mp4
  readme.txt
```

If you run `python src/my_script.py` from `project_dir`, `directory` will be `/project_dir/src`, but the script's working directory will be `/project_dir`.

As a result, this code:

```
    result = model.transcribe(video)
```

Will look for `video.mp4` in the working directory, when you really want to look for it in the source directory.

Either do this:

```
    result = model.transcribe(os.path.join(directory, video))
```

Or make this change to the previously discussed line:

```
directory = os.getcwd()
```

If you do indeed want to only operate on videos in the working directory.

Of course, you need to make sure your videos are actually in the working directory in that case.

Comment: Thank you. I definitely had a misunderstanding of what a working directory is. I tried this and it worked. Thank you so much!